# Nativescript angular style split the scss file into two platform specific scss files (.android.scss / .ios.scss)

Tags: angular, sass, styles, nativescript

I've modified my component to transform that in a nativescript angular platform specific SCSS one
and is working (the background of the button is yellow on android platform/simulator and green on IOS one as specified in SCSS files) even though it gives me the error: "*Error: HostResourceResolver: could not resolve ./auth.component.scss in context of*" please see below (see the image attached) into the **auth.component.ts**

I tried with something like this:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'ns-auth',
   templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./auth.component.ios.scss', './auth.component.android.scss'],
   moduleId: module.id,
  })
```

but is not working. It takes in consideration only the last one (android in this case), ignoring the first (ios) one.

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple but not obvious (looking for the documentation).
I have created an empty **auth.component.scss**
that will be used for commun properties.

Now the structure look like in the image below:

[image]